# Weighted average over two columns in different tables

Tags: dax

I have a table called `Products` and another table called `Sales`. They are related by `ProductId`. I need to find the weighted average for a selected list of products in `Products` table. The formula is

```
(Product1.UnitCost * Sales[ProductId1].ItemsSold +
 Product2.UnitCost * Sales[ProductId2].ItemsSold + ...) /
(Total sum of the chosen products items sold)
```

How can I write a DAX formula for this?

```html
Products
   
ProductId   | Name  | Description   | UnitItemCost
------------|---------|---------------|----------------
id1     | Name1 | Description1  | 10
id2     | Name2 | Description2  | 20
id3     | Name3 | Description3  | 30
   
   
Sales 
  
ProductId  | ItemsSold
-----------|--------------  1714.126984
Id1    | 20  
id2    | 30  
id1    | 10  
id2        |    40  
id3    | 50  
id3    | 39  

Average unit cost = 23.12    (10*30+20*70+30*89)/189
```

Comment: Can you give some example data and the expected output?

Comment: @AlexisOlson Have added a sample in there

Comment: Shouldn't your average unit cost in the above example be 23.12, as opposed to 1714.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the logic in your above example. It looks like you're trying to take `UnitCost * ItemSold` for each product, sum that all together and divide by the total `ItemSold`.

That should be `((10*30)+(20*70)+(30*89)) = 4370` divided by `189`, which is `23.12`.

If that's the case, you can created a calculated measure like so:

```
Average unit cost = 
--create a summary table, one row per product id, with a 'Cost * Sold' column giving you UnitItemCost * ItemSold for each product
VAR my_table =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Sales,
        Sales[ProductId],
        "Cost * Sold", MAX ( Products[UnitItemCost] ) * SUM ( Sales[ItemSold] )
    )
RETURN

--take the sum of UnitItemCost * ItemSold for each product (4370 in your example) divided by the total ItemSold (189 in your example) 
    SUMX ( my_table, [Cost * Sold] ) / SUM ( Sales[ItemSold] )
```

As long as your Products and Sales tables are related via ProductId, this should work. After testing it on my end with your sample data, I'm getting 23.12.

Comment: Thanks you. You are right it is 23.12.  In the formula, SUMX ( my_table, [Cost * Sold] ) / SUM ( Sales[ItemSold] ), in the denominator SUM ( Sales[ItemSold] ), will the row context be applied or will take all the rows in Sales table and sum them?

Comment: The row context will be applied, provided that you have your relationship set up between the two tables. You can therefore filter your data to include only your selected list of products and the measure result will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. It helps

Answer (score 0):

As Rory points out, your `1714.126984` value does not seem to match your example, but the weighted average unit cost can be calculated using a relatively simple measure:

```
Average unit cost = DIVIDE(
                        SUMX(Sales,
                            Sales[ItemsSold] * RELATED(Products[UnitItemCost])),
                        SUM(Sales[ItemsSold]))
```

This is the sum-product of the items and their associated cost divided by the total number of items sold.